# Get the value of the selected "select box" with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

Having more than one select box in the form, **how can I get the value of the one that was selected** without using ids?

The following code is always returning the value of the first selected box.

```
$('form[name=test]').on('change', function () {
    alert("Value: " + $('select').val());
});
```

Comment: try  alert("Value: " + $(this).val());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: You can bind change event handler to all select boxes using `select` jquery tag selector and use `this` (which is nothing but the select box instance on which change event occur) to read the changed value.

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    alert("Value: " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar honestly i don't get why replicate the same identical answer as mine, but whatever

Comment: @pumpkinzzz, it is just coincident. It is not so complicated and more than one person can think of same solution. Also you can see there is only a minute of difference between our post. I have put logical explanation to my answer and it seems that you added explanation later. Don't take it personally but this happens on SO, I also faced this earlier but you cannot say that someone copied your answer.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i’m not saying you copied answer, that was an obvious one. But when i answer and i notice someone else already did i just delete my post, and eventually comment the other answer. I feel that’s the correct behave, but like i said, whatever. peace

Answer (score 1):

The [`event`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-eventData-handler) argument is passed to the callback function and the `currentTarget` attribute on the event is the element that the event is operating on;

```
$('select').on('change', (e) => {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
$("form[name=test] option:selected" ).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. register the *change* event to all the **select** (not the form)
2. use **this** keyword to get the one that triggered the event

try this

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    alert("Value: " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @HillelGarcia np mate :) feel free to mark as correct answer